# (Django / Nginx / Gunicorn) HTTPS fails to serve pathed directories on my site

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Pretty new to Nginx and web deployment in general. I have a site I am aiming to deploy using a DigitalOcean droplet. Right now it is working, but only with `http://[SERVER-IP]` ([here](http://46.101.92.95/))

Although the site *does* load with HTTPS ([here](https://rejesto.com/)), no `domain.com/[ X ]`  sites work.

The aim is to make get all URLs within https://rejesto.com functioning normally and leading to their respective sites.

For context, all links on the page are provided by Djagno's `{% url '[url]' %}` tag system; they work as intended locally, and using `http://[SERVER-IP]/[ X ]`.

---

I'm **assuming** that the issue is within the Nginx config files because:

1. http://46.101.92.95/blog leads to the correct page. *(for better or for worse)*
2. https://rejesto.com/blog does not work.

Here is *(what I believe to be)* the relevant config file:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/rejesto.com`:

```
server {

   server_name rejesto.com www.rejesto.com;
   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/rejesto/myprojectdir;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                   
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/rejesto.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rejesto.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot                  
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot                    
                                                                                           
} 

server {
    if ($host = www.rejesto.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = rejesto.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name rejesto.com www.rejesto.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name 46.101.92.95;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/rejesto/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

---

For additional context, I was following these tutorials provided by Digital Ocean:

- [How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04)
- [How To Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Try removing `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` from the / location block. I think this is not needed as Django handles your paths from the web app.

Comment: @Marco You've got me hitting myself, this worked immediately. One of those "hours over one line of code" situations. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx configuration is incorrect.

1. Uninstall certbot and remove all the certificates.
2. Use this nginx configuration:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name www.rejesto.com;
       return 301 $scheme://rejesto.com$request_uri;
    }
   server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name rejesto.com;
       location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
       location /static/ {
            root /home/rejesto/myprojectdir;
        }
        location / {
             include proxy_params;
             proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 46.101.92.95;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root /home/rejesto/myprojectdir;
        }

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Initialise nginx:

   sudo nginx -t
   sudo systemctl restart nginx
4. Reinstall certbot and issue your certificates.

Answer (score 0):

```
'settings django: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['exemple.com','ip']

Dns pointe vers le domaine ? 

systemctl restart gunicorn 
systemctl restart nginx

proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/gunicorn.sock'
```